# Permisson Denied when tried to copied file from location to cointainer

Tags: docker, jmeter

I'm follow steps in [Here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-using-docker/) to set up a distributed test by Jmeter but in copy my local jmeter test into the master container I got a permission denied error, specifically

`sh: 2: /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/: Permission denied`

Comment: Did you `chmod +x` in `/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter` file? Assumption: You work on a Linux ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to copy a file from your Host to Docker container, why not just mount the file/directory in to the container during runtime using `--mount` or `-v`. For example: `docker run -v <local path>:<dst path on docker container> <ImageName>`

Edit: This works between multiple containers as well. You can use SharedVolumes to share storage between 2 or more containers. Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands:

1. `docker exec -t master chmod +x /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter.sh`
2. `docker exec -t slave01 chmod +x /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter.sh`
3. etc.

This will make [jmeter.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1/bin/jmeter.sh) script executable via [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.